# JSON escape space characters

Tags: html, json, escaping, character

How would I escape space characters in a JSON string? Basically my problem is that I've gotten into a situation where the program that reads the string can use HTML tags for formatting, but I need to be able to use these HTML tags without adding more spaces to the string. so things like

```
<u>text</u>
```

is fine, for adding underline formatting

but something like

```
<font size="14">text</font>
```

is not fine, because the `<font>` tag with the size attribute adds an extra space to the string. I know, funny criteria, but at this point thats what has happened.

My first speculative solution would be to have some kind of \escape character that JSON can put in between font and size that will solve my "space" problems, something that the HTML will ignore but leave the human readable string in the code without actual spaces.

```
 ex. <font\&size="14">text</font>
```

displays as: `text`

kind of like `&nbsp;` but better?

any solutions?

Comment: Why does space need escaping??

Comment: Expand for us on why a space needs to be escaped in JSON. As one poster shows, this is possible, but escaping a space does not change the meaning of the JSON, and only increases its size — ie, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: the JSON is creating strings in a field of an object. `"Object" = { "attribute1": "key", "attribute2": "integer", "attribute3": "string"}`, there is a separate platform that parses the JSON objects, attribute 3 happens to be parsed as HTML, so it can use HTML tags to further format the text. But the platform makes assumptions about the number of spaces in the string. Adding certain HTML tags will add spaces to the string. I need a way to add spaces without REALLY adding spaces to the human viewable user experience.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use \u0020 to escape the ' ' character in JSON.